Next.js App Deployed on Digital Ocean - Cannot GET Custom Paths
I have a Next.js app that I've deployed on Digital Ocean, but I'm running into an issue when trying to access custom paths.
Project Structure:
The project has two separate directories: a backend directory using TypeScript and Express, and a frontend directory using Next.js and its pages router.
Deployment Steps:
Build the Next.js project in the frontend directory.
Copy the out directory from the frontend to the backend's static directory.
Build the backend project.
Build Steps:
cd ../frontend
npm i
npm run build
cp -r out ../backend/static
cd ../backend 
npm run build

Run Steps:
npm start

Issue: The app deploys successfully, but when I try to directly enter in URLs like https://<DO-URL>/auth/login or refresh browser I get a "CANNOT GET '<url-path>'" error. I suspect it's because the client is sending a GET request to the path, but since the frontend uses Next.js, it might not be configured properly.
Next.js Configuration (next.config.js):

/\*\* @type {import('next').NextConfig} \*/
const { hostname } = require('os')
const path = require('path')

const nextConfig = {
output: 'export',
images: {
unoptimized: true,
remotePatterns: \[
{
protocol: 'http',
hostname: 'localhost',
},
\],
},

reactStrictMode: true,
swcMinify: true,
sassOptions: {
includePaths: \[path.join(\__dirname, 'src/styles')\],
},
}

module.exports = nextConfig

Question: How can I fix this issue and ensure that custom paths in my Next.js app work correctly when deployed on Digital Ocean? Is there a way to configure the backend server to handle Next.js routing properly?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you
I tried implementing a catch all GET HTTP endpoint in express that tries to resolve path to index.html but this did not work
